# i'm a new learner in jupyter and don't understand this error, i'm looking to remove the $ sign

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

`MKT['Income'] = MKT['Income'].str.replace('$', '')`

i get this error  [enter image description here][1]

```
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Income'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-5ea6ddc03a8c> in <module>
----> 1 MKT['Income'] = MKT['Income'].str.replace('$', '')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Income'
 


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WszY.png
```

Comment: print `MKT.columns` possibly the column name has some whitespace

Comment: In `pandas` a `KeyError` is raised when you're trying to access a column that doesn't exist.  It's saying that in your `MKT` dataframe, there is no column called `Income`.

Comment: thanks you @RaghavaDhanya that was the problem !